# Where can I view JUnit test results in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-studio, android-testing

I have a simple test class:

```
public class SimpleTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void testSomething() throws Throwable {
         Assert.assertEquals(1 + 1, 2);
    }
}
```

I know how to run the test, but where can I view the output in Android Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the test by right clicking on it.

[image]

The run tab should pop up, you can open it by hand on the very bottom left corner.

[image]

It will list your test results.

Comment: Is this it? No proper way to view & run individual tests and see if passed or not (as in VS)?..

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with finding it at first, but eventually, I have managed to find it within the Debug window, under the Console tab.

[image]

It shows both progress (status bar) and test results (print within the console).

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but it could be helpful.

I have Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 and you just need to click on two different options just to show all nested results.

[image]

If you click on these two options, it will show all the results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go to "Run" in the menu list in Android Studio,  then click on "Run", a popup menu shows up, select from it which test you wish to run. Once you run it, you'll have the figure as shown in the attached screenshot: green progressbar means tests were successful, red progressbar indicates at least one of tests failed.For more details, visit android developers website [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test#view_the_test_results)

[image]